# Android GridLayoutManager even row spacing

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager

I have a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. Items are added dynamically, span size is calculated based on text length. So far it looks like this:
[image]
I want to add even horizontal spacing for each row like so:
[image]

I assume i need to extend GridLayoutManager class and override some method, but not sure where to look. Perhaps there's some other way to implement this? I appreciate any help and hints.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411183/7666442

Comment: worked like a charm. thank you. Please, post an answer so that i can accept it