# How to align recycler view items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to align RecyclerView items. I am using ChipsLayoutManager so that i can get items side by side it is working but it is leaving lots of space and i want the next item to be continue where the first end.

Here is the code:

```
ChipsLayoutManager chipsLayoutManager = ChipsLayoutManager.newBuilder(Quran_e_Kareem.this)
                //a layoutOrientation of layout manager, could be VERTICAL OR HORIZONTAL. HORIZONTAL by default
                .setOrientation(ChipsLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL)
                // row strategy for views in completed row, could be STRATEGY_DEFAULT, STRATEGY_FILL_VIEW,
                //STRATEGY_FILL_SPACE or STRATEGY_CENTER
                .setRowStrategy(ChipsLayoutManager.STRATEGY_DEFAULT)
                // whether strategy is applied to last row. FALSE by default
                .build();
        listView.setLayoutManager(chipsLayoutManager);
```

[I am getting output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNgJE.jpg)

[But i want to get this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTfeR.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Simple use [`FlexboxLayoutManager`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) for sample check this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49973416/7666442 && https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411183/7666442

Comment: **Please don't repeat questions.** Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers didn't work, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since you seem to have gotten your solution there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Comment: I get my answer but still having some issue in it so i ask again

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

```
   ChipsLayoutManager chipsLayoutManager = ChipsLayoutManager.newBuilder(this)
                        .setOrientation(ChipsLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL)
                        .build();
```

Comment: If u see in my question i am using same but it didn't according to my requirement please once see the images will get it

Comment: remove this line  .setRowStrategy(ChipsLayoutManager.STRATEGY_DEFAULT)

Comment: After remove that line also same no changes in output