# How to make FlexboxLayout scroll?

Tags: android, android-flexboxlayout

I am using Android FlexboxLayout in one of my Activities, but when the content is larger than my screen, I cannot scroll there to see it. All examples seem to scroll be default, but it just doesn't do that in my code.

The XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:id="@+id/fbRoot"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:alignContent="flex_start"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:flexWrap="wrap">

    .. a lot of other views ..

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411183/7666442 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49973244/android-gridlayout-with-dynamic-number-of-columns-per-row/49973416#49973416

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it inside a [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:id="@+id/fbRoot"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:alignContent="flex_start"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:flexWrap="wrap">

    .. a lot of other views ..

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
</ScrollView>
```