# Adding Horizontal full screen card in staggered grid layout in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayout

I know how to use staggered grid layout, but this layout design is beyond me. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this layout design? I have done layout design like this before.

[image]

But the desired layout is like this.

[image]

The problem is the 4th card can't be inflated as the way it is in the design, with staggered grid layout. So I want to know how I can achieve this type of layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`FlexboxLayoutManager`**](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview)

Use like this

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_END);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

Comment: @DanielJrMcCoy if u need demo then check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/49973416/7666442 && https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411183/7666442

Comment: I am on it. Thank u @Nilesh